# Can ping OPC UA server, but cannot connect to it

Tags: ping, ethernet

I have an OPC UA server running on a PLC from BR Automation and would like to connect to it from UaExpert running on a Windows 10 machine.
It has worked previously, but after physical re-placement of the components and installing a new ethernet cable, I cannot connect to the server any more:

```
GetEndpoints on EndpointUrl failed with 'BadTimeout', retrying on all DiscoveryUrls
Could not connect to server: BadHostUnknown
```

However, I am still able to ping the OPC UA server. Security and Authentication Settings are unchanged on my side. I have no possibility to access the settings on the server side, but there is no reason why they would have changed. They have never changed in the past.

The new ethernet cable has a length of about 40 meters. Maybe that is an issue?

Does anyone have a suggestion why I cannot connect to the server, even though I can ping it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the OPC UA application was either not properly configured or not running at all.

I do not have direct control of the OPC UA server. Instead, I have to call the company who operates it every time I want something checked. That is why I tried to rule out possible other causes before calling them.